# Include contents from one view to another in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I m new to CodeIgniter so i m facing some problem regarding adding contents from one view to another.
 I have three views header, contents and footer and want to put these views in one main container with 960px width.

coz i m new so expecting some simple answer.

My code is this

```
public function index()
{
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('content');
        $this->load->view('footer');            
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this.

```
$output  = $this->load->view('header', 'your_data', true);
$output .= $this->load->view('content', 'your_other_data', true);
$output .= $this->load->view('footer', 'your_last_data', true);

$this->output->set_output($output);
```

For more [Info](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Displaying_Multiple_Views/)

Answer (score 1):

Just call the views inside the main view

```
  public function index()
    {
        $data['content']['title'] = 'title';
        $data['content']['body'] = 'body';
        $this->load->view('layout',$data);         
    }
```

In views/layout.php

```
<div id="main_container">
    <?php
       $this->load->view('header',$content);
       $this->load->view('content',$content);
       $this->load->view('footer');  
    ?>
</div>
```

Ex. in views/header.php

```
<title>.<?php echo $title;?></title>
```

in views/content.php

```
<div id="main_body"><?php echo $body;?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function index()
{
      $data['title']        ="Details";
      $this->load->view("headerview",$data);
      $data['batches']  =$this->detailsmodel->getname();
     $this->load->view('content',$data);
     $this->load->view("footerview");
}
 // something similar to this ?
```

Didn't understand ur question properly brief what u want ? is this the answer u looking for

Comment: Why you think that he has a view named "view"?

Comment: @RupeshPawar sorry it should be content